# How to filter path results based on a specific node with a specific property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prxQO.png)

I have a query to find the paths between two nodes.  Now, I want to find any paths that have a node with a status = 'down'.  However, the only query that works is to find paths without any nodes with a status of down.

Here is the query that is able to give me all the paths without a node with a status = 'down'.

```
MATCH path=((dev)-[r:part_of|CONNECTS*..20]-(dev2))
WHERE dev.hostname = 'fwmc0208-01' AND dev2.hostname = 'cemc0208-01.edg'
WITH nodes(path) AS n
  WHERE NONE(node IN n WHERE (node.status IS NOT NULL) and node.status = 'down')
RETURN n
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cnPX.png)

If I replace NONE with ALL, I get zero results.  I've tried flipping the status to equal 'up', but this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `ANY` function:

```
MATCH path=((dev)-[r:part_of|CONNECTS*..20]-(dev2))
WHERE dev.hostname = 'fwmc0208-01' AND dev2.hostname = 'cemc0208-01.edg'
WITH nodes(path) AS n
  WHERE ANY(node IN n WHERE (node.status IS NOT NULL) and node.status = 'down')
RETURN n
```